# What's the difference between ">=" and "*" in npm if current installed version is the latest

Tags: node.js, npm

Suppose I've installed the latest package, which is `0.10.12` and then I have two options to specify the version in `package.json` - `'somelib':'>=0.10.12'` or `'*'`. I understand that the first options says that any version above `0.10.12` should be installed, if there is any. The `*` says that the newest version available will be installed. But if I run `npm update somelib`, won't they both install the newest version? If so, then why use the former?

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm install` will install the newest version of the module in both cases.

The difference shows in dependencies

- `>=` it's required to have the version of the module or newer.
- `*` it doesnt matter at all wich version of the module you have. Any will
  do.

See [npm package documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

Comment: so what you're saying is that `*` won't install newer version even if it's available?

Comment: so if they both install the newest version, what's the difference? can you provide a use case that shows the difference?

Comment: As I said in my answer, It doesn't make a difference when using `npm install`. The difference is when setting up dependencies.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'setting up dependencies'. Can you elaborate?